# How to get a PessimisticLockException with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, locking, jpa-2.0, pessimistic-locking

I am trying JPA's support of database locking in order to avoid concurrent requests in a record. In my scenario I need to use a pesssimistic lock. I got that using the following approach:

```
EntityManager em;
...

Map<String,Object> props = new HashMap<String,Object>();
props.put("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 0);
em.find(MyEntity.class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ, props)
```

but with that approach I handle a `LockTimeoutException` instead of a `PessimisticLockException`. **How to handle a `PessimisticLockException` specifically**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the spec, the `PessimisticLockException` only occurs on a transaction-level rollback:

> When the lock cannot be obtained, and the database locking failure
>   results in transaction-level rollback, the provider must throw the
>   PessimisticLockException and ensure that the JTA transaction or
>   EntityTransaction has been marked for rollback.

Your transaction seems to consists only of that single data retrieval query and the persistence provider considers that if a lock error occurs on that query, then the rollback would be considered as a statement-level rollback. Which according to the spec would result in the `LockTimeoutException`:

> When the lock cannot be obtained, and the database locking failure
>   results in only statement-level rollback, the provider must throw the
>   LockTimeoutException (and must not mark the transaction for rollback).

I think thats a clever way of the driver / persistence provider to give you a chance to repeat / fix your statement instead of rolling back the whole transaction implicitly.

In general, I think that if you had an insert or an update before that find (or some more complex data manipulation statements), then you would get the `PessimisticLockException`.